# Unusual error message in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am getting a strange error message that says

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

Still cannot find out why, I am building a .NET website with registration and all and it has worked fine until I added two parameters for the `registrationpart`. Here is the code hopefully some one can tell me what is wrong. I have googled around for an answer but cant seem to get it right anyway.

```
public partial class UserPages_Register : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

   protected void btnRegisterRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        //If passwords do not match, error
        if (textPasswordRegister.Text != textPassword2Register.Text)
        {
            lblErrorRegister.Text = "Passwords must match.";
        }
        else
        {
            //If user has uploaded image it gets saved in folder
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ProfileImages/") + filename);
                textProfileImageRegister.Text = (("~/ProfileImages/") + filename); 
            }
            else {
                //Otherwise a standard avatar is used
                textProfileImageRegister.Text = ("~/ProfileImages/Avatar.png");

                //Data put in textboxes gets inserted into DB
                SqlConnection con6 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jaklin11ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                con6.Open();
                string insCmd = "INSERT INTO [Users] (FirstName, LastName, Birthdate, Gender, Weight, Height, Email, Password, Town, AreaCode, ProfileImage) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Birthdate, @Gender, @Weight, @Height, @Email, @Password, @Town, @AreaCode, @ProfileImage)"; 
                SqlCommand insertUser = new SqlCommand(insCmd, con6);

                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", textFirstNameRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", textLastNameRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", textBirthdateRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ddlGenderRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Weight", textWeightRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", textHeightRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", textEmailRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textPasswordRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProfileImage", textProfileImageRegister.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Town", texttown.Text);
                insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaCode", textareacode.Text);

            try
            {
                insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con6.Close();
                Session["Email"] = textEmailRegister.Text; //User gets logged in
                Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/Default.aspx"); //Send to startpage
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                lblErrorRegister.Text = "An error ocurred."; //Otherwise error
            }
```

Comment: For the record all parameters exist in a SQL-databse that is connected to the webpage, it all worked untill I added AreaCode and Town into the Users tabel

Comment: You need to print out the exception itself - don't catch the exception and just ignore it. The exception will tell you *what* went wrong.

Comment: How do you print out an exception? Mostly everything has gone softly and smooth in the programming, untill I added two parameters to the database-table and two parameters to the website

Comment: Instead of printing `"An error occured"` in the `lblErrorRegister`, print the message of the exception: `catch (Exception ex) { lblErrorRegister.Text = ex.Message; }`.

Comment: The problem is solved! changed the error message to ex.Message and it worked perfectly!

Comment: You should consider dropping ADO.NET for Entity Framework or at least build a data access layer and decouple the insert code from the register logic. Your code is in really bad shape: no error logging, no database connection disposing, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$     
ConnectionStrings:jaklin11ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT [Activity], [Distance], [Date], [Time], [WorkoutID] FROM [Workout] 
WHERE ([Email] = @Email) ORDER BY [Date] DESC">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:SessionParameter Name="Email" SessionField="Email" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Changed the CSS-code for the datasource, the fault was that it didint have a condition. So I added WHERE Email = @Email

Answer (score 1):

Since you say you had an `SqlException`, I'll guess that the most likely reason is that the INSERT command failed, possibly because of a duplicate row - do you have a UNIQUE constraint on any of the columns you're inserting?

For example, this could happen if the `btnRegister` is clicked twice.

I don't think the change you made to the catch block in the answer you posted will make any difference.  In general it's better to log the exception details with a full stack trace, and display a user-oriented error message to the end user, i.e. instead of:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    lblErrorRegister.Text = ex.Message; //Otherwise error
}
```

You should use

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    log(ex.ToString()); // call your favourite logging library
    lblErrorRegister.Text = "An error occurred"; // or something more friendly
}
```

Logging `ex.ToString()` is better than just `ex.Message` as you'll get other useful information such as a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
  try
        {
            insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con6.Close();
            Session["Email"] = textEmailRegister.Text; //User gets logged in
            Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/Default.aspx"); //Send to startpage

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            lblErrorRegister.Text = "An error ocurred."; //Otherwise error
        }
```

Changed that to:

```
  try
        {
            insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con6.Close();
            Session["Email"] = textEmailRegister.Text; //User gets logged in
            Response.Redirect("~/UserPages/Default.aspx"); //Send to startpage

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblErrorRegister.Text = ex.Message; //Otherwise error
        }
```

Although it was a minor change it made the program run smoothly again. Sometimes .NET is really strange...

Comment: Could you highlight the code section that you changed (e.g. only post that part)? It's hard to see what is different in those samples.

Comment: I don't think this change will make any difference.  Possibly you clicked the register button twice when you got the original error.